# Где скачать "чистый " сервер (Denwer)?

Tags: php, denwer

Привет. Хочу потренероватся в установке всех пакетов на чистый сервер с нуля (например самому поставить БД). Подскажите ссылку где такой можно достать. Буду рад любой информации по этому поводу.

Comment: думаю на оф. сайте Денвера и лежит чистый денвер. а так, на сайте php.su тоже есть полезная инфа

Comment: если "чистый" - то уже не денвер, советую переименовать вопрос во что-то типа «Подскажите где скачать "чистый" сервер»...

Comment: Тогда тут Denwer не причем. Начните с установки Linux.

Comment: А ставить куда собираетесь? Т.е. ось какая?

В сети куча мануалов по тому как ставить каждую компоненту отдельно. Т.е. описывается как скачать и поставить Apache, затем PHP, затем как их связать, как поставить MySQL и подключить к первым и т.д.

Вас это интересует?

Если с извращениями хотите - можете из сорцов собрать каждое в отдельности и с настройками при конфигурировани/комплияции повозиться

Comment: Все что ты написал это моя цель,но боюсь я щас не справлюсь.У меня Windows.

Comment: А зачем вам экспериментировать с Windows, если все хостинги на nix?

Comment: Для практики.

Comment: Так "поставить БД на Windows" и "поставить БД на Linux" - это совсем разные вещи. Ваша практика будет почти бесполезной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

недавно подготовил статейку http://smart-core.org/wiki/Установка_веб-сервера_на_Windows

кстати, замечу, что IIS на винде работает раза в 3 быстрее апача с mod_php, также надо всегда помнить, что апач на винде работает в 10 раз медленней, чем на линухе.

Comment: ВАВ ВАВ ВАВ.

Answer (score 4):

Советую использовать [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/). У него гораздо больше преимуществ перед Денвером, я давно на него перешел.

Comment: + и не надо париться на счет установки, и обновлении версий )

Answer (score 3):

Denwer - это набор уже готового и собранного ПО в одну кучу, если я не ошибаюсь. А просто HTTP-сервер - это Apache, на данный момент Denwer использует Apache 2.2.22

Comment: и на все следующие моменты, денвер вроде как discontinued. и правильно.

Comment: спасибо Вам.

Comment: @eicto пруф ?

Comment: тут где-то было... я не пользуюсь, у меня debian

Comment: @eicto Специально полез на офф сайте Denver'a :), там пишут что скоро выход 4 версии, последнее обновление changelog'a за 2012-09-16, как то странно для discontinued проекта... и у меня тоже  

    user@pc:~/soft$ uname -a
    Linux pc 3.2.0-38-generic-pae #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:39:51 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: зато апач 2.2 не странно :)

Comment: > там пишут что скоро выход 4

@sonniy, они это пишут уже два года ;)

Comment: ого :D , а что они так заглохли ?

ЗЫ сам то я на glass fish